# SeriLog in Asp.Net Core web app does not inject dependency properly

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

In `Startup.cs` `Configure()` method, I setup the logger like below:

```
        Serilog.Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.RollingFile(new CompactJsonFormatter(), "c:\\temp\\myapp.json")
            .CreateLogger();

        loggerFactory.AddSerilog(Serilog.Log.Logger);
```

ILogger and Log.Logger always evaluates to Serilog.Core.Pipeline.SilentLogger instead of what is setup. Am I missing any step in setting up DI?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen in some **Autofac** scenarios where the `builder.RegisterLogger();` method is called without passing an `ILogger`, but for whatever reason **AutofacSerilogIntegration** fails to detect the previously created logger.

If you have an `ILogger` instance, you can pass it to the container builder explicitly like this:

```
builder.RegisterLogger(logger);
```

where logger is an ILogger implementation.

Answer (score 0):

To get mine to work, I had to call the AddProvider method.

Something kinda like this:

```
        /* ok, need to get ILoggerFactory, i don't like this call to BuildServiceProvider, but that's what I had to do for my console-app (dotnetcore, not aspnetcore) */
        ILoggerFactory ilf = servColl.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<ILoggerFactory>();


        /* now create the SerilogLoggerProvider */
        Serilog.Extensions.Logging.SerilogLoggerProvider seriprovider = new Serilog.Extensions.Logging.SerilogLoggerProvider(serilogger, false);
        /* now cast the SerilogLoggerProvider to ILoggerProvider */
        Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerProvider castSerilogger = seriprovider as Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerProvider;

        /* now register the castSerilogger */
        ilf.AddProvider(castSerilogger);
```

The above is a less-smooth version of something like this:

https://andrewlock.net/adding-serilog-to-the-asp-net-core-generic-host/

https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-hosting

Here are a few breadcrumbs in case the above links fail

```
"public class SerilogLoggerFactory : ILoggerFactory"

"_provider = new SerilogLoggerProvider(logger, dispose);"
```